# Determine offsetTop of an element and set it on other element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a list of items. If an item is clicked anoter view is revealed beside the item. I want this view to have the same offsetTop as the item. I know how to do this in jQuery, however cannot find a solution in pure angularjs. This is what I tried so far

```
top = angular.element('#user'+user.id).prop('offsetTop');
angular.element('#feed-details').css('margin-top', top);
```

This has no effect. Any ideas how to achieve this in angularjs?

Comment: This depends on your layout (read: your CSS code) which we don't know. Is the second view floated, absolutely positioned, …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lengths must have a unit. `offsetTop` is a unitless number. So just add `"px"` to it.

That said, you could just do it in [Vanilla JavaScript](http://vanilla-js.com/):

```
document.getElementById('feed-details').style.marginTop =
            document.getElementById('user'+user.id).offsetTop+"px";
```