# How to calculate the distance between the top-left corner of an HTML element and the window top-left corner?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Is there an easily way to do that? Consider having properties like: border, padding. Would that method work even with box-sizing: content-box/border-box?

Comment: element.getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: I will accept it if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps I do not understand your question, but

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetLeft
(Or same link except offsetLeft, I can't post more then 2 links yet :P)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect

Let me know if those links don't solve it!

Comment: The second link is what I needed but +1 goes to dandavis who already responded to it in the comments of my question.

Comment: wonderful! I am new here so I didnt realize to check those, glad you found the answer!

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5CnV3/)**

Perhaps you may be looking similar to [position](https://api.jquery.com/position/) or [offest](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) in jquery can be simply achieved by using jQuery as follows

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dores.</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var $box = $('.box');
alert( $box.offset().top)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but I wanted it in vanilla javascript :)

Comment: I am not sure but this link may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115380/determine-offsettop-of-an-element-and-set-it-on-other-element

Answer (score 0):

The function

> element.getBoundingClientRect()

solves the problem.

More about it can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect